# pymongo sort dictionaries inside of an array by date

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want some of your knowledge in here.

What I'm trying to do, is to sort the dates **(datetime)** of the dictionaries **(from the oldest to newest)** which is inside of an array from my MongoDB database.

```
{"_id": {
"$oid": "63595cb35e81b89cb442087c",
"Carrots": [
{
  "task": "Plantation",
  "date": "2022-01-16T00:00:00",
  "info": "Yes it worked"
},
{
  "task": "Cleaning",
  "date": "2022-01-25T00:00:00",
  "info": "Yes it worked"
},
{
  "task": "Cleaning",
  "date": "2022-01-08T00:00:00",
  "info": "Yes it worked"
},
{
  "task": "Grass-cutting",
  "date": "2022-01-28T00:00:00",
  "info": "Yes it worked"
},
{
  "task": "Cleaning",
  "date": "2022-01-09T00:00:00",
  "info": "Yes it worked"
},
{
  "task": "re-plantation",
  "date": "2022-01-10T00:00:00",
  "info": "Yes it worked"
},
{
  "task": "Grass-cutting",
  "date": "2022-01-23T00:00:00",
  "info": "Yes it worked"
},
{
  "task": "re-plantation",
  "date": "2022-01-01T00:00:00",
  "info": "Yes it worked"
},
{
  "task": "re-plantation",
  "date": "2022-02-14T00:00:00",
  "info": "Yes it worked"
},
{
  "task": "re-plantation",
  "date": "2022-02-02T00:00:00",
  "info": "Yes it worked"
}]}
```

I have tried with `f = mycol.find({'Carrots':{"$exists":True}}).sort("date", 1)` but is not working for this example.

What I did and was returning me the correct format was the following:

```
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient['GARDEN']
mycol = mydb['garden_data']

f = mycol.find({'Carrots':{"$exists":True}})
for i in k:
        data = i['Carrots']
data.sort(key=lambda x: str(datetime.strptime(str(x["date"]),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')))
print(data)
```

I have a ***solution on my project***, but **I want to know how to make the same exact thing with pymongo**.

I have also seen that some people are using `mycol.aggregate` but I couldn't find something understandable enough, so I can make it work.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `$sortArray`:

```
pipeline = [
  {"$project": {
      "Carrots": {
        "$sortArray": {
          "input": "$Carrots",
          "sortBy": {"date": 1}
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
f = mycol.aggregate(pipeline)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w-sZX3z3UOE)

Comment: On the playground it works completely fine. Actually the ```sortBy``` must be ```sortBy: {date: 1}``` as I discovered just now.
But when I try to run it with python it returns me a syntax error ```{$project: {
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `pymongo` syntax for aggregation. maybe [this](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/aggregation.html) can help

Comment: Okay buddy, thanks for you answer, I really appreciate that you took the time and help me!
I will try to work on it a little bit more and see how your question can be used with python.

Comment: Maybe my last update (with quotes for the keys) will help

Comment: Not that is important for you at the moment, but ```"sortBy": "{date: 1}"``` must be like this ```"sortBy": {"date": 1}```.
Still it didn't worked and now the error is the following ```pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Invalid $project :: caused by :: Unknown expression $sortArray, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Invalid $project :: caused 
by :: Unknown expression $sortArray', 'code': 31325, 'codeName': 'Location31325'}```

Comment: OK. This may be due to your mongodb version. `$sortArray` is since version 5.2...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249108/discussion-between-bilakos-and-nimrod-serok).